# cite references in the text by superscript numbers and listed at the end in order they are cited in the text

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, superscripts

How I can cite references in the text by superscript numbers and listed at the end of the paper in the order in which they appear in the text e.g

1. Engel KH, Heidlas J, Tressl R. Food is wonderful, I can't get enough. In Food Flavours Part C. The Flavour of Fruit, Morton ID, MacLeod AJ (eds). Elsevier: Amsterdam, 1990; 195.

Is there any natbib and apalike combined style?

Comment: A small example of code to start with would help

Comment: My document class is amsart and I am using package \usepackage[round]{natbib} and \bibliographystyle{apalike}. My bibliography is like                  @BOOK{ZW,
 author={Zhou, Y. Q. and Weng, Z. Xi.},
 title={Reliability {G}rowth},
 publisher={Science Press, Beijing China},
 year={1992},
}                                                            when I compiled got Zhou and Wang (1992). But now I want to cite in text as Zhou and Wang with number of reference in superscript in the order in which they appear in text.

Comment: Do you still want to use the `apalike` bibliography style -- albeit with the bib entries sorted by order of citation rather than alphabetically -- or are you looking for a different bibliography style? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, i want apalike style.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `biblatex` with these options (check you have the `biblatex-apa`:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, sorting=none,autocite=supercript]{biblatex}
```

Numeric is the default bibliography and citation style of biblatex. You can specify the backend: bibtex, bibtex8 or biber. The default is `biber`, and some features of boblatex can be accessed only with it; moreover, it understands UTF8 for .bib files, which simplifies greatly if you have accented letters in your references.

Comment: When i complied my file in WinEdt, I got " 
Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid".

Comment: @Ahmed: When I wrote my answer I didn't know you were using `apalike`. I'll update my answer in a moment. But apalike is not a numeric style, is it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using BibTeX. If that's the case, you could get superscript-type citation callouts by loading the [natbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package with the option `super`:

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

---

*Addendum*: To create a customized version of `apalike.bst` that does *not* perform alphabetical sorting of the bib entries, you could follow the following steps:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX file system. (You might type `kpsewhich apalike.bst` to find out where the file is.) Make a copy of this file, calling the copy (say) `myapalike.bst`. (Do *not* edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open `myapalike.bst` in an editor of your choice. The editor you use to edit your .tex files will dd fine.
- Locate the two lines that start with `SORT` -- uppercase form matters. (In my copy of this file, the lines are 1025 and 1084.)
- Comment out these lines (or delete them outright, if you prefer).
- Save the file `myapalike.bst` either in the directory where your main .tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- Start using the newly modified bibliography style by inserting the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{myapalike.bst}
  ```

  (and, of course, deleting the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike.bst}`). Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all the changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks Mico your suggestions. I tried it and somehow problem is solved except one things. I also want author name like Zhou and then key should appear in superscript of Zhou. Now i have only key but not author name.

Comment: @Ahmed - When you say that the "key" should appear in the superscript, do you mean the value of the entry's key field, viz., `ZW`?

Comment: Key mean unsrtnat key which is now ok. But in reference list reference should appear like this:                              1. Engel KH, Heidlas J, Tressl R. Food is wonderful, I can't get enough. In Food Flavours Part C. The Flavour of Fruit, Morton ID, MacLeod AJ (eds). Elsevier: Amsterdam, 1990; 195.

Comment: Is there any natbib and apalike combined style?

Comment: @Ahmed - I've provided an addendum to my answer, to show how the bibliography style `apalike` might be modified so that it no longer sorts the bib entries alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks, but let me to ask another small thing. How I can display author name using Vancouver style?

Comment: @Ahmed - Since your follow-up question isn't particularly related to the topic of the current question, please post a new question to this site. That way, it'll be far more likely to be seen by more than just me. :-)