# How to make numbered and ordered references for a paper to be submitted to a Springer journal?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I have a bibtex file like following:

```
 @inproceedings{NWS-2003,      
        Author =     {W.Nejdl and M.Wolpers and W.Siberski and C.Schmitz and M.Schlosse and I.Brunkhorst and A.Loser},
          Pages =    {536-543},
          Title  =    {Super-peer-based routing and clustering strategies for RDF-based peer-to-peer networks, in: Proceedings of the 12th International Conference on World Wide Web WWW},
  Year =     2003
}

@article{PGW-2010,
  Author =   {A.Padmanabhan and S.Ghosh and S.Wang},
  Journal =  {J Grid Computing},
  Pages =    {365-389},
  Publisher =    {Springer},
  Title  =   {A Self-Organized grouping SOG framework for efficient grid resource discovery},
  Volume =   8,
  Year =     2010
}
```

I try to write under Springer journal format, with numbered references,
in the text the first references NWS-2003 is cited before the second PGW-2010, so for me it is supposed that in the text and in the reference section NWS-2003 should be the first [1], and PGW-2010 is the second [2]
 but when I compile the file, it ordered  references alphabetically, and not as their sequence of appearance.

I use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and for `\bibliographystyle` I have tried with: `%\bibliographystyle{aps-nameyear}`
`\bibliographystyle{spbasic}`
`\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}`

and `\bibliographystyle{spphys}` this later does not give me a full reference but only the authors names and the publisher name.

Comment: i'm not sure it works for springer journals, but in other situations, `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` leaves the references in the same order as they're referred to in the text.

Comment: Whatever else you may decide to do, you must insert spaces between the first-name initials and the surnames.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188240/5001) for a discussion of how to go about modifying (a copy of) the bibliography style file so that alphabetical sorting is no longer performed. The answer in the link give above deals with the `apalike` bibliography style; however, the method described there is fully applicable to the `spbasic` style as well.

Answer (score 2):

- See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188240/5001) to the posting [cite references in the text by superscript numbers and listed at the end in order they are cited in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188219/5001) for step by step instructions on how to go about modifying a bibliography style file so that alphabetical sorting is no longer performed. The answer works not only with the `apalike` bibliography style, but also with `spbasic`.
- Assume you've created a copy of the file `spbasic.bst` that doesn't perform alphabetic sorting, and suppose you've named the new file `spbasic-nosort.bst`. You really still need to fix several errors in the bibliography. Just in the two entries you've provided in your posting, several errors jump out. Most importantly, you *must* leave whitespace between the first-name and surname components of all authors' names. Next, in both `title` fields, be sure to encase acronyms that consist of uppercase letters (e.g., "SOG" and "RDF") in curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing them. Furthermore, in the entry with key `NWS-2003`, (i) one of the author's surname is mis-spelled (it should be entered as `L{\"o}ser`, not `Loser` [!]); (ii) the `title` and `booktitle` fields have inexplicably been merged; do split the field into two parts by creating a separate `booktitle` field; and (iii) the title field needs an extra piece (the part in parentheses should be "WWW2003", not just "WWW").

In my view, getting the *contents* of all bib entries absolutely correct is far more important than is fretting over alphabetically sorted versus unsorted entry styles.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytest.bib}
@inproceedings{NWS-2003,      
  Author   = {W. Nejdl and M. Wolpers and W. Siberski and C. Schmitz and M. Schlosse and I. Brunkhorst and A. L{\"o}ser},
  Pages    = {536-543},
  Title    = {Super-peer-based routing and clustering strategies for {RDF}-based peer-to-peer networks},
  booktitle= {Proceedings of the 12th International Conference on World Wide Web (WWW2003)},
  address  = "Budapest, Hungary",
  Year     = 2003,
}

@article{PGW-2010,
  Author =   {A. Padmanabhan and S. Ghosh and S. Wang},
  Journal =  {J Grid Computing},
  Pages =    {365-389},
  Publisher ={Springer},
  Title  =   {A Self-Organized grouping ({SOG}) framework for efficient grid resource discovery},
  Volume =   8,
  Year =     2010,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic-nosort}

\begin{document} 
\cite{PGW-2010} \cite{NWS-2003}
\bibliography{mytest}
\end{document}
```