# How to add location in ACM-Reference-Format.bst ? also related: How to order by citation the bibliography with ACM-Reference-Format.bst?

Tags: bibliographies, acm

ACM-Reference-Format.bst order alphabetically .
i want to use this ".bst" and ordering by appearance in the final document. Also i want to add the location. Examples:

[3] Fröhlich, B. and Plate, J. 2000. The cubic mouse: a new device for three-dimensional input. In Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems (The Hague, The Netherlands, April 01 - 06, 2000). CHI '00. ACM, New York, NY, 526-531. DOI= http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/332040.332491.

the new format shows without location

[3] Fröhlich, B. and Plate, J. 2000. The cubic mouse: a new device for three-dimensional input. In Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems . CHI '00. ACM, New York, NY, 526-531. DOI= http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/332040.332491.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which entry type you used for the entry at hand. Actually, please edit your query to post the entire bib code for the entry.

Comment: On the subject of modifying the bst file so that it no longer performs sorts the entries alphabetically by authors' surnames, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188240/5001) to the query [... references ... listed at the end in the order they are cited in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188219/5001). (Shameless self-citation alert!) Just follow those instructions, while substituting `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` for `apalike.bst`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The location is a part of the book title,

   booktitle={Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in 
   Computing Systems (The Hague, The Netherlands, April 01 - 06, 2000). 
    CHI'00}
2. Currently alphabetic sorting is required for all ACM citations.