# Cite references in text by superscript and in the bibliography as numbered

Tags: citing, overleaf, superscripts

I have looked at this other post ([cite references in the text by superscript numbers and listed at the end in order they are cited in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188219/cite-references-in-the-text-by-superscript-numbers-and-listed-at-the-end-in-orde)) with a similar problem, which as been solved, but I am using the following code to do my citations, is there something I can do to get what I want without switching everything over to how the answers in the link did it?

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{sample}
```